# How to suppress warnings on cross join select without where clause in sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, cross-product

When doing something like :

```
import sqlalchemy as sa

with session() as S:
  print(S.execute(sa.orm.select(A, B)).all())
```

sqlalchemy display this warning :

```
<ipython-input-2-fe928e97d8b6>:1: SAWarning: SELECT statement has a cartesian product between FROM element(s) "A" and FROM element "B"
```

However... A cartesian product (called cross product elsewhere...) is exactly what I am doing and want to do...

So how to suppress this warning ?

Comment: It’s only a warning. Have you read [Built-in FROM linting will warn for any potential cartesian products in a SELECT statement](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/changelog/migration_14.html#built-in-from-linting-will-warn-for-any-potential-cartesian-products-in-a-select-statement)?

Answer (score 0):

The warning can be suppressed by setting `enable_from_linting` to `False` when creating the engine:

```py
create_engine(connection_url, enable_from_linting=False)
```